# How to minimize a frameless window which has been set size to fixed by method setFixedSize in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

### How to minimize a frameless window which has been set size to fixed by method setFixedSize in Qt?

Hi, 
I'm using C++ code to make a Qt application. I set the window to frameless by

```
this->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

So I can't click the minimize button support by Operating System and I made a customed one. But, when I want to use

```
this.showMinimized();
```

I found that it can't work with window which has been set fixed size by

```
this.setFixedSize(width, height);
```

So my question is, is there some other ways to make the window minimized which can be used by a window that set fixed size?

Comment: This is essentially the same question you asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444406/how-to-let-a-frameless-widget-which-has-been-set-fixed-size-show-minimized-in-qt).  The effect of the `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` flag is OS specific but, if your window has no `minimize` button then that suggests the window manager is being bypassed.  Since it's generally the window manager that's responsible for minimizing/maximizing windows I suspect you're out of luck.  This does sound like a bit of an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Why do you need a frameless window?

Comment: For me, I want to make a program looks as I wish, so I decide to use DIY window manager.

Comment: This is strange. setMinimized() works perfect on Windows, but no use on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 0):

This is almost definitely not what you are looking for, but most if not all modern operating systems contain a minimize-all keyboard shortcut or show desktop button.  You may have the button on your task bar, if you have one.  If not, try windows-key+d or control-alt-d.  If you want to learn about how to minimize a qt window from within your code(what I think you probably want), I recommend you check out the surprisingly clear documentation at [doc.qt.io](http://doc.qt.io).

Comment: Thanks to you. But now I'm using the frameless window, which means the minimized button is not shown.

Comment: Sorry.  I figured any answer was better than none, if there is a slight chance of it being useful.